# How does negative lookahead with asterisks work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand why I'm not getting the expected results from a regex.

I already know what is negative lookahead (apparently not :-))  And also that asterisks is zero or more times of repeats.

Looking at this regex :

```
a(?![^3])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will match `a` which isn't  followed by  a `non-3` after it.

So looking at this test string  , the bold part is a match:

> **a**3333335

Ok

Also- if I change the regex to :

```
a(?![^3]+)  //notice "+"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It will still match :

> **a**3333335

This will match `a` which isn't followed by a non-3's ( at least one)

**Question**

My problem is with `*` :

Let's change the regex to  :

```
a(?![^3]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will not match

> a3333335

But my question is -  why ?

According to the drawing :

`a` should not be followed by  : *Either* nothing **or** *neither* non-3's

But this is DOES happening : `a` is not followed by nothing **AND** is not followed by non3-'s

So why it doesn't match ?

*And to make my life more difficult :*

Looking at this regex :

```
a(?![^3]*7)
```

This will match :

> **a**3333335

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that an **asterisk can generate the empty string** (`""`), and you can say that **between every character and the next one, there is an empty string**.

Given the regex:

```
a(?![^3]*)
```

and you query with `a33333`, you more or less say: reject if there are zero or more repetition of non-3's after `a`, but there is such repetition: the empty string, so without even capturing a single `3`, it will reject. The matching thus looks like:

```
a    (?![^3]*)
"a"     ""   "33333"
```

(quotations mark strings, and are no characters here)

You can thus say that the **negative lookahead, of a regular expression over a *Kleene star* will always reject** (one must be careful, in the sentence I mean that the Kleene star is unified over the "entire" regular expression, this does *not* imply that a negative lookahead containing a Kleene star will always reject).

Your image shows this as well:

[image]

It says *if not followed*, it means that it cannot match what is inside the box. The problem is, that it doesn't have to take a single character to reach the end of the box.

---

This does not hold for `a(?![^3]*7)`: here you say "*reject if you encounter zero-or more *non-3*'s followed by a seven. Since the regex `[^3]*7` doesn't match `3333335`, the lookahead will not reject the match.

Comment: Kleene is the researcher who is credited with the star (`*`), he was one of the "founders" or regular expressions. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: I've been dealing with regex for almost 10 years now , but never proved that I should take care of empty strings(?!??) and between every characters there is empty string (!?!) does `/a+/`  deals also with empty strings ? no. its just look at the following chaceters and search for another "a"/ if it was empty string after "a" , then "aaa' would fail here. ( of course , i'm not arguing. just want to be corrected :-))

Comment: @RoyiNamir: because one must carefully formulate statements, perhaps: *between every character and the next one, there is an empty string* is a better way to specify it. See it like this: the regex `a(b*)c` also matches, `ac`, this because `b*` is selected with zero repetitions and thus the empty string. For the string `ac` there is thus an empty string between `a` and `c`.

Comment: Furthermore if you for instance split a string by the empty string, you will obtain all the characters individually: `"test".split("")` will return `"t","e","s","t"`.

Comment: ^ nice proof. so how come `/a+/g` matches `a""a""a""` ?

Comment: Because, `a+`, is equivalent with `a(a*)` (added brackets to make bindings explicit). Furthermore the quotes are not part of the string, these are added in the answer to make the empty string explicit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: any as in zero-or-more, but I agree it is ambiguous. Replaced it. It doesn't work for `+` because `+` is one-or-more.

Comment: What do you mean  by it doesn't work. if I change * to + [it does work](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dceP8If-a9iSODae)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: the rejection of the string doesn't work. I see negative lookaheads as a device that is looking for a way to reject a previously made match in every possible way.

Comment: One last thing , can you explain in short example what you meant by : _one must be careful, in the sentence I mean that the Kleene star is unified over the "entire" regular expression, this does not imply that a negative lookahead containing a Kleene star will always reject_ ?

Comment: The statement says that for instance `(?!.*)` `(?!(ab)*)`, `(?!(a|b)*)`... will always reject. But not a negative lookahead containing the star: like `(?!ab*c)` `(?!(a|b)*(c|d))`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Being pedant  , but I think your last line should be : _Since there is no seven to be seen after the **empty string** after the `a` in a3333335, there is thus no reason to reject the string_...am I right?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: but the negative lookahead aims to find a match, so it is not said it *will* unify with the empty string. For instance `a(?!b*c)` will reject `abbbc` and `ac` as well.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: updated it with a less ambiguous expression.

Comment: Now i'm confused, didn't you say that "*" generates empty string ? and that I should now think of `a` as  `a""` ?

Comment: `*` *can* generate the empty string, and in this case it *will* generate the empty string. But as said before *negative lookahead* looks to find its pattern to reject the match. So it will attempt all possible repetitions of `3`. The point is that one of these is the empty string, and since the empty string is between every character and the next, the empty string can always be found in a string.

Comment: So  `a(?![^3]*7)` will reject **only because** first "a" is not followed by an empty string which is followed by 7 ( empty string because of "*")....no ?

Comment: only **if** `a` is followed by (the empty string and) `7`; or one or more non-3s and then `7`. So `a7` will be rejected. `a57`, `a127`. But will "fail to reject" `a3`, `a337` `a537`, `a3` `a12`...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `*` would repeat ***zero*** or more times. **Zero** non-3s (aka empty string) included. Nothing doesn't mean the *end of the string*, it means literally *nothing* (empty string).

The reason why the example with `7` works is because the lookahead will try to match as many non-3s as possible. At the position after the `a`, that would be *zero* non-3s. After that, it will try to match exactly **one 7**. But the next character is **3**, therefore the lookahead will not fail the matching of `a`.

Comment: Well, there is no quantifier after the 7. Therefore, you want to match exactly one 7. Are there some non-3s, followed by a 7? No, there is no 7.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, added better explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To understand why:

```
a(?![^3]*)
```

fails to match you can change your lookahead to:

```
a(?!.*)
```

which will also fail and reason being the same that your lookahead assertion that `a` must not be followed by anything including empty string will always return false hence **your regex will always fail**.

2nd regex is this:

```
a(?![^3]*7)
```

which succeeds because there is really no 0 or more of `non-3` followed by `7` in your input.

If you change your input to e.g. `a7` then it will fail the match.

Comment: I don't understand your middle paragraph. According to your alternate regex : I see it as : _don't select `a` if his following characters be empty ( worst case)_"  BUT THEY AREN'T EMPTY. they are all 3 ....so ?

Comment: No, `a(?!.*)` doesn't mean that **match `a` if it is not followed by empty string** For that you need `a(?!$)` and that will succeed. ``a(?!.*)`` means if it is not followed by 0 or more of any character. This last assertion of **not followed by 0 or more of any character** will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the * is behaving the same way as it would anywhere else.

**[^3]*** will match every string because it matches "as many not 3s as possible including none".

**a(?![^3]*7)** Should match "any 'a' not followed by as many not '3's as possible including none and a '7'." which is equivalent to "any 'a' not followed by a 7 unless the they are separated by '3's".