# Find lines that do not contain 1 of 2 characters in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, emeditor

how can i find lines that NOT contain either chars `;` or `:`?

i only know to find line without one of them by regex `^[^\:]*\r\n`

thanks!

Comment: Lines ? With this `^[^;:\r\n]*$` ?

Comment: it work! thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following, you can select blocks of consecutive lines that do not contain those characters:

```
^[^:;]*$
```

For the following input file, this regular expression will select lines 1-2, 4-6, 8-9 (skipping line 3 and 7, which contain the excluded characters).

```
1
2
3A : 3B
4
5
6
7A ; 7B
8
9
```

Comment: how it would be now if i want to find all lines contain both chars?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a ?! for negative lookahead.

I like to use this site to try out regex I write. https://regex101.com/

https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: This is wrong. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661162/how-does-negative-lookahead-with-asterisks-work)

Comment: How do you use lookahead, in OP's case?

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of EmEditor. If you use EmEditor, you can enter `[;:]` to the Filter toolbar, and turn on both **Use Regular Expression** and **Negative** buttons. [Filter toolbar in EmEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYE3D.png)